# Array search, add and delete

Tags: php

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, entry_id INT NOT NULL, last_change timestamp);
INSERT INTO sample (entry_id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
```

My code does the following:

- Receives POST input and compares the values to the table above.
- If the the POST data has a value that does not exist in the entry_id column, then it will perform an `INSERT` statement.
- If the table has a value in the entry_id column that does not exist in the POST data, then it will perform a `DELETE` statement

PHP Code:

```
<?php
// $_POST data:
$submittedEntries = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6);

// $dbORM->getEntries()
$currentEntries   = array(
    array("id" => 100, "entry_id" => 1, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 2:14:00"),
    array("id" => 101, "entry_id" => 2, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 2:14:00"),
    array("id" => 102, "entry_id" => 3, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 2:14:00"),
    array("id" => 103, "entry_id" => 4, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 2:14:00"),
)
$entriesToAdd     = array();
$entriesToRemove  = array();

// Find Entries to Add
// Loop through each entry submitted
foreach($submittedEntries as $entry_id) {
    $exists = false;

    // Loop through all Current Entries
    foreach($currentEntries as $existingEntry) {
        // Find matching IDs
        if ($existingEntry["entry_id"] == $entry_id) {
            $exists = true;
        }
    }

    if ($exists == false) {
        $entriesToAdd[] = $entry_id;
    }
}

// Find Entries to Remove
// Loop through all Current Entries
foreach($currentEntries as $existingEntry) {
    $remove = true;

    // Loop through each entry submitted
    foreach($submittedEntries as $entry_id) {
        // Find matching IDs
        if ($existingEntry["entry_id"] == $entry_id) {
            $remove = false;
        }
    }

    if ($remove == true) {
        $entriesToRemove[] = $existingEntry["entry_id"];
    }
}

// Add New Entries
foreach($entriesToAdd as $entry_id) {
    $dbORM->addEntry($entry_id);
}

// Remove Entries
foreach($entriesToRemove as $entry_id) {
    $dbORM->removeEntry($entry_id);
}

$entries = $dbORM->getEntries(); // SELECT * from sample;
print_r($entries);

/*
    Expected Output:

    array(
        array("id" => 100, "entry_id" => 1, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 2:14:00"),
        array("id" => 102, "entry_id" => 3, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 2:14:00"),
        array("id" => 103, "entry_id" => 4, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 2:14:00"),
        array("id" => 104, "entry_id" => 5, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 3:27:00"),
        array("id" => 105, "entry_id" => 6, "timestamp" => "2014-07-24 3:27:00")
    )
*/
```

Is there a better way to do this? I looked into all the php array functions and they do not seem to be able to deep search of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to just `DELETE` stuff that isn't in the post. It would be better to track which items you want to remove in your app then specify the ids you want removed. A misconfiguration in your form submission could drop all your data otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm in a position where I am unable to modify the front-end code that sends the POST data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table has to always be exactly like the `POST`, simplest way is to `DELETE` all rows and then `INSERT` all posts.

Another solution could be the use of unique key on entry_id...
This way you could really simply do 2 small queries:

```
$insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO sample (entry_id)VALUES(".implode('),(',$submittedEntries).")";
$delete = "DELETE FROM sample WHERE entry_id NOT IN(".implode(',',$submittedEntries).")";
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not an option as my table actually has many other columns that cannot be cleared when this update function is performed.

Comment: Could we please have a bit more info on your table then? Because in your example, you simply select * from sample

Comment: Ok, for example.. my table has a timestamp value:

CREATE TABLE sample (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, entry_id INT NOT NULL, last_change timestamp);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compair the two lists in PHP then you can use `array_walk()` to run through the db list and then use `in_array()` to see if it's in the submitted POST. You can then filter into two arrays.

```
<?php
$entriesToAdd     = array();
$entriesToRemove  = array();

$submittedEntries = array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6);
$currentEntries   = array(
    array("id" => 100, "entry_id" => 1),
    array("id" => 101, "entry_id" => 2),
    array("id" => 102, "entry_id" => 3),
    array("id" => 103, "entry_id" => 4),
);

function AWS(&$item, $key) {
    global $submittedEntries, $entriesToAdd, $entriesToRemove;

    if(in_array($item["entry_id"], $submittedEntries))
    {
        array_push($entriesToAdd, $item);
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($entriesToRemove, $item);
    }
}
array_walk( $currentEntries, 'AWS' );

echo "Add:";
print_r($entriesToAdd);
echo "Remove:";
print_r($entriesToRemove);
```

This outputs:

```
Add:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 100
            [entry_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 102
            [entry_id] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 103
            [entry_id] => 4
        )

)
Remove:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 101
            [entry_id] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what your looking for, but it's a possible way to approach assoc arrays